# NodeJS Skinning

Tags: node.js, skinning

Is there a module or similar things that support skinning in NodeJS? I want to build a NodeJS website, and want to be able to re-skin the website as I like without much efforts, like in Wordpress.

Is skinning supported in NodeJS?

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the whole concept of node.js here

Comment: Wordpress = house you can paint; node.js = material that can be used to create bricks which in turn may be put together to build a house which you might eventually paint.

Comment: @jsalonen I don't think I misunderstood nodejs, I think I just did not make myself more clear in the question, I am using NodeJS, Jade, Express, and I know about Calipso CMS for NodeJS, but because for some reasons I cannot use that CMS, so I thought there could be something that can provide skinning for website built in top of NodeJs but not part of CMS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're interested in building a website in Node.js and don't need a wordpress-style cms behind it, there are few projects that can help you out.

Have you looked into [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)? It's built with less which you can easily plug in to your Express setup (see the guide here, using the command line executable to set up a new project you can specify less like this: `express --css less myapp` and it will do all the work for you)

In the bootstrap less file are several variables you can use to change the colours, fonts, sizes, etc, and it's also got a lot of helpers for grid layouts and responsive designs.

It even includes a few useful javascript plugins too which make the ui nicer with less work.

There are also a lot of [sites with themes](http://bootswatch.com) and [theme generators](http://www.boottheme.com) around which then work on top of bootstrap, and may achieve what you want.

Plugging in this sort of solution (whether bootstrap or other) is about as close as you can come to getting skinning for node; As otherwise suggested if you're looking for a CMS out of the box as well, probably best to look for another platform like Wordpress.

Comment: Just came across this site, which is a really good [roundup of resources for Bootstrap](http://designshack.net/articles/css/20-awesome-resources-for-twitter-bootstrap-lovers/). Worth a look if you're using Bootstrap, in addition to the two I linked above.

Answer (score 3):

Node.js is not a content management system. It is a platform on top of which you could built a web server with a content management system. To answer your question you need to be looking for *node.js based content management systems that support themes*.

The only node.js CMS that I am aware of is [Calipso](http://calip.so/). It's still pretty alpha-stage. It may have some theming support, but it is nowhere near as polished as Wordpress.

Also is there a reason why you want to use node.js? I mean there is nothing wrong in using Wordpress for creating a themeable website - it is just awesome for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want another OnlineShop, or maybe a blog, i think nodejs is  maybe not your right choose as Jed Watson told.

If your requirements are more complicated, and you want a quick and easy implementation of a nice web interface, and you have html, javascript, and css knowledge... I strongly recommend you just trying to work with [MEAN.js](http://meanjs.org/)

It puts together MongoDB Expressjs, AngularJs, and NodeJs.

Use this, for example with a [yeoman fullstack constructor](http://yeoman.io/learning/index.html) and you will have a powerful webapp, with user autentication, and much more in a few minutes.

After that, the use of jade, less, scss, and similar languages of modelling the front, and the easy way you can also model collections in the back, is for me the best combination you´ll find for creating a website today.

Hope it´ll help you
King Regards